# diamond shape in android studio

Tags: android, shapes

I'm having trouble using a path to create a diamond shape on Android studio. It looks like I have a little more than half of the diamond, but I don't know what I am doing wrong and why the rest of it isn't printing out. I've been trying to change my code for hours and nothing is working. Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong? Here is my code so far:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape;

public class Diamond extends Shape {
private int strokeWidth;
private final int fillColor;
private int strokeColor;
private Path path;
private Paint strokePaint;
private Paint fillPaint;

public Diamond(int strokeWidth, int fillColor, int strokeColor) {
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
    this.strokeColor = strokeColor;

    this.strokePaint = new Paint();
    this.strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    this.strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

    this.fillPaint = new Paint();
    this.fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    this.fillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);

}
@Override
protected void onResize(float width, float height) {
    super.onResize(width, height);
    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(width/2, 0);
    path.lineTo(width, height);
    path.lineTo(width/2, height*4);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    path.close();



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just need to change `path.lineTo(width/2, height*4);` to instead multiply the height by 2 as in `path.lineTo(width/2, height*2);`, using 4 makes the bottom half skewed longer than the top.  There's also an example on [this page](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/drawing-triangles-rhombuses-and-other-shapes-on-android-canvas) drawing a rhombus which you can modify to draw a diamond by using the full width like:

```
public void drawRhombus(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, int x, int y, int width) {
    int halfWidth = width / 2;

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x, y + width); // Top
    path.lineTo(x - halfWidth, y); // Left
    path.lineTo(x, y - width); // Bottom
    path.lineTo(x + halfWidth, y); // Right
    path.lineTo(x, y + width); // Back to Top
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```